# rails5: How one can exclude retweet and replies from search api?

Tags: ruby, twitter, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to fetch tweets using API, but i don't want any retweets and replies. By research i came up with solution that "-is:retweet" and "-is:reply" operators can be used to exclude retweets and replies.

I am simply using search query

```
tweets = client.user_timeline('userName', count: 20)
```

As, I am new to rails and twitter api, i don't how to use both the given operators in search query.

Even any alternative answers would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You tweet's have methods to check for both so you should be able to simply do

```
tweets.reject{|tweet| tweet.retweeted_tweet? || tweet.reply? }
```